# Confusion about prior used in Recursive Bayes Filter

Tags: bayesian, estimation, prior, computer-vision, recursive-model

I'm currently using [this thesis](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Eajd/Publications/Strasdat-H-2012-PhD-Thesis.pdf) to understand key concepts about probabilistic inference in computer vision which is being a great source.

The frame of the question is the following:

> Let us assume we would like to estimate a parameter $\mathbf{x}$ over time. At each time step
> $1, \ldots,  t$, we observe a set of measurements $\mathbf{z}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{z}_{t}$.
> We are interested to estimate **the posterior distribution**, or belief at time t:
> $$bel(\mathbf{x}_t) := p(\mathbf{x}_t|\mathbf{z}_1,\ldots, \mathbf{z}_t)$$
> Using the recursive Bayes Filter scheme, we get:
> $$ bel(\mathbf{x}_t) \propto p(\mathbf{z}_t|\mathbf{x}_t) \int p(\mathbf{x}_t|\mathbf{x}_{t-1})bel(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}) d\mathbf{x}_{t-1} = p(\mathbf{z}_t|\mathbf{x}_t) \cdot p(\mathbf{x}_t| \mathbf{z}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{z}_{t-1})$$

Where the asumptions made have been:

- The probability of the current state $\mathbf{x}_t$ only depends on the previous state $\mathbf{x}_{t-1}$
- The measurements at timestep $t$ ($\mathbf{z}_t$) are dependent only upon the current state $\mathbf{x}_t$

A graphic description of these assumptions would be the following (*image extracted from* [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_Bayesian_estimation)):

[image]

Given this, what I'm having difficulties to understand is the following implementation of the previous result:

> Assuming a Gaussian distribution, $bel(\mathbf{x}_t)$ is proportional to
> $$\exp(-(\mathbf{x}_t - \mathbf{x}_{t-1})^T \Lambda_{\mathbf{x}_{t-1}} (\mathbf{x}_t - \mathbf{x}_{t-1})\cdot \exp(-(\mathbf{z}_t - \hat{\mathbf{z}}(\mathbf{x}_t))^T \Lambda_{\mathbf{z}} (\mathbf{z}_t - \hat{\mathbf{z}}(\mathbf{x}_t))$$

I believe that the second part, $\exp(-(\mathbf{z}_t - \hat{\mathbf{z}}(\mathbf{x}_t))^T \Lambda_{\mathbf{z}} (\mathbf{z}_t - \hat{\mathbf{z}}(\mathbf{x}_t))$, relates to the likelihood $p(\mathbf{z}_t|\mathbf{x}_t)$. However, if this is the case, what I don't understand is the following relation:

$$\int p(\mathbf{x}_t|\mathbf{x}_{t-1})bel(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}) d\mathbf{x}_{t-1} = p(\mathbf{x}_t| \mathbf{z}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{z}_{t-1}) \\ \xrightarrow[]{\text{relation?}}\exp(-(\mathbf{x}_t - \mathbf{x}_{t-1})^T \Lambda_{\mathbf{x}_{t-1}} (\mathbf{x}_t - \mathbf{x}_{t-1}))$$

I feel that here, the author is using a density function for $p(\mathbf{x}_t|\mathbf{x}_{t-1})$ instead of $p(\mathbf{x}_t| \mathbf{z}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{z}_{t-1})$. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $p(x_t| z_1, \dots, z_{t-1})$ should not depend on $x_{t-1}$ since it is integrated out.

Comment: [This article](http://user.it.uu.se/~thosc112/pubpdf/schonl2011.pdf) may provide useful for figuring out the densities in recursive  Bayesian filtering for Normal Distributions.

Comment: Thanks @hakanc, I agree with you, and because of that, the term: $$ \exp(-(\mathbf{x}_t - \mathbf{x}_{t-1})^T \Lambda_{\mathbf{x}_{t-1}} (\mathbf{x}_t - \mathbf{x}_{t-1})) $$ is confusing me. I am going to have a look at the link. Thanks for it.

Comment: Hi: This isn't meant to imply that the link can't be helpful but you can think of it the following way. The term inside the integral without the $d x_{t-1}$ can be thought of as the joint density of $x_{t}$ and $x_{t-1}$ ( just use conditional density formula ). Then, since you are integrating over $ d x_{t-1}$, you end up with  just the density of $x_t$. Then, since $x_{t}$ is markov, it only depends on $x_{t-1}$ so that is why the term after the right arrow arises. The term after the  right arrow contains the random parts involved and  leaves out the scale factors.

Comment: Thanks @mlofton, following your reasoning and knowing that the integral part represents $$p(x_t| z_1,...,z_{t-1})$$ Would it make sense to assume that the previous state $x_{t-1}$ is given/ known so it can be treated as a constant (mean of the density function)?

Comment: By the way @hakanc, althought I wasn't able to fully understand my question with the link provided, I found it a good source to gain insight in related topics, so thanks again for it :)

Comment: @Javier TG: Yes, if they are asking for the density of $x_{t}$, then it's usually (AFAIK ), okay to assume that everything before time $t$ is known. And I agree that the link does look quite useful. I just don't have the time to go through it right now so thanks to hakanc.

Comment: Okey, that makes sense to me, thanks @mlofton

Answer (score 1):

So in the thesis, the statement
$$
\int p(x_t|x_{t-1}) bel(x_{t-t}) dx_{t-1} = bel(x_{t-1})
$$
is misleading, borderline wrong. $\int p(x_t|x_{t-1}) bel(x_{t-t}) dx_{t-1}$ should give a density in $x_t$ which is what the author uses in eq. (2.33). What he means is that
$$
\int p(x_t|x_{t-1}) bel(x_{t-t}) dx_{t-1} = p(x_{t})
$$
where the distribution $p(x_{t})$ depends on a fix and prior value of $x_{t-1}$. In eq (2.33) and eq (2.34) $x_{t-1}$ is treated as a fix and given parameter, and he assumes that
$$
p(x_t) \propto \exp\left( -(x_{t} - x_{t-1})^\top\Lambda_{x_{t-1}} (x_{t} - x_{t-1})\right),
$$
which could mean that
$$
p(x_t) = \mathcal{N}(x_t; x_{t-1}, \Lambda_{x_{t-1}}).
$$

Comment: Thank you. Following your response, does it mean that $p(x_t | z_{1}, ..., z_{t-1}) = p(x_t)$? i.e. that the current state $x_t$ is independent of the previous measurements?

Comment: It is unclear what he means and assumes. If you want to learn about Bayesian recursive filtering, I suggest looking for tutorials on the topic.